# Receive messages/events from SQS and map them to Dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I am trying to figure out a way where I can read my SQS events and map them to DynamoDB using Java. I have a SQS in AWS which will get some messages having some information e.g. `{"id": "xxx", "state": "xxx"}`. These events I want to map them in my DynamoDB table. The DynamoDB contains `id` as a partition key.
According to my reasearch this is doable by reading messages from sqs and use `putItem` from AWS DynamoDB in JAVA.
Is there any simple way to that using JAVA. Or any example would be helpful here.

Thank you !

Comment: There's plenty of online documentation and examples of how to use Java in AWS Lambda with both SQS and DynamoDB. Use those to write some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AWS, there is a JAVA SDK 2.0 specifically design for this:

Generic Example of Receiving Messages from an SQS Queue:

```
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl(queueUrl)
        .maxNumberOfMessages(5)
        .build();
    List<Message> messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).messages();
```

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/fb99a9b5453c61c13a032b9c225986c865ba4705/javav2/example_code/sqs/src/main/java/com/example/sqs/SQSExample.java#L152

---

Generic Example of Putting an Item into DynamoDB:

```
 HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemValues = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();

// Add all content to the table
itemValues.put(key, AttributeValue.builder().s(keyVal).build());
itemValues.put(songTitle, AttributeValue.builder().s(songTitleVal).build());
itemValues.put(albumTitle, AttributeValue.builder().s(albumTitleValue).build());
itemValues.put(awards, AttributeValue.builder().s(awardVal).build());

PutItemRequest request = PutItemRequest.builder()
        .tableName(tableName)
        .item(itemValues)
        .build();

ddb.putItem(request);
System.out.println(tableName +" was successfully updated");
```

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/fb99a9b5453c61c13a032b9c225986c865ba4705/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/PutItem.java#L84

AWS documentation is excellent and so are its examples:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/fb99a9b5453c61c13a032b9c225986c865ba4705/javav2

Official Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services.html